# SSAS Tabular - Other options to update tables rather than Process Full...?

Tags: sql, ssas, ssas-tabular

We have a fairly large SSAS Tabular cube with many different tables (some which contain measures and dimensions, etc). On occasion we will run into scenarios where I have to optimize the cube partitions (break  them into smaller parts) or cube structure so that not as much memory is consumed when it processes (daily). Occasionally we've had to increase the memory limits of the server just to make sure the job doesn't crash. One of our sql server consultants asked if we had considered changing the process mode on the scripted job to 'Default' rather than 'Full' (since every table in the script is set to full in the process mode). I said I hadn't considered this but my concern is that, it seems based on my research, that default won't actually update the data but will really only replenish the tables structure if it changes in some way. I need a processing mode that will just pull in any new rows (and update any rows that have changed) since the last time the partition was processed. Is there any mode which accomplishes this rather than Process full (which obviously wipes the current partition it's processing and rebuilds the entire thing = memory intensive)? Anything less memory intensive that will still pull in new rows and update outdated ones?

fyi, all the tables are based on sql queries

Answer (score 1):

One option is doing a Process Data instead of a Process full on the tables in your tabular model.  You may also want to consider implementing partitioning in your tables in order to take advantage of the ability for SSAS to process these in parallel.  Since your tables are already based on SQL queries, you'll only need to modify the filters in the queries to make the data uniform across multiple partitions.  Partitioning the tables will also allow for incremental processing using Process Add to incrementally update the partition.  Looking into other ways to reduce unnecessary memory, such as removing unused columns and replacing calculated columns where possible (read about the cost calculated columns [here](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/storage-differences-between-calculated-columns-and-calculated-tables/)) will also help the memory issues.

Comment: We do currently use partitions to break the data into different time periods. Will using 'Process Add' pull in just new data and then update any records that have changed? And what's the difference between Process Add and Process Data?

Comment: Process Add will pull in new rows and does recalculations, while Process Data only reloads the data.  For updated records, you'll need to set up your partitions and processing schedule/settings accordingly to account for this.